# Error in SP while translating from Oracle to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am translating procedure from Oracle to Snowflake and getting an error:

[image]

The procedure is:
https://github.com/santas-little-helper-13/sql/blob/main/sp.sql

Comment: Look in the query history and see what the exact text of the SQL the SP tried to run was.

Answer (score 0):

I see that ":" is missed when using variables in a SQL statement or assigning the result of a SQL statement to a variable. Please check this part:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html#using-a-variable-in-a-sql-statement-binding

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html#setting-variables-to-the-results-of-a-select-statement

This is a long SP so you may probably hit other errors. Good luck with the rest of the code.